# Run ansible-playbook from code/command line connecting to docker container

Tags: python, ansible

I am using this:

[Specify docker containers in /etc/ansible/hosts file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47600633/specify-docker-containers-in-etc-ansible-hosts-file)

to run my ansible playbooks against a docker container.

But is there any way to avoid having a physical `/etc/ansible/hosts` file with the information about the container? E.g. run it from code where this information can be configured?

I looked at:

[Running ansible-playbook using Python API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27590039/running-ansible-playbook-using-python-api)

but when looking at the answers I see variables pointing to physical files, e.g.:

```
inventory = Inventory(loader=loader, sources='/home/slotlocker/hosts2')
playbook_path = '/home/slotlocker/ls.yml'
```

So not really sure why that is better than simply just calling from command line without using the Python ansible API.

Comment: Check out this link: https://serversforhackers.com/c/running-ansible-2-programmatically. It uses a 'NamedTemporaryFile' to make a new inventory file.

Comment: Why do you want to run ansible playbooks against running docker containers? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: To be able to test my play books faster, e.g revert the target machine/container faster

Answer (score 0):

May be install Ansible in Docker container and then run it locally inside the container. For example in the Dockerfile, include:

```
# Install Ansible
RUN pip install ansible
COPY ansible /tmp/ansible
# Run Ansible to configure the machine
RUN cd /tmp/ansible && ansible-playbook -i inventory/docker example_playbook.yml
```